# Load a XAML Layout dynamically based on User interaction

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Good day, I am quite new to windows phone and so please bear with me. I have a requirement to load a XAML layout based on what the user chooses. For example, if i have 4 XAML layouts A, B, C, D, when the user chooses C, the respective XAML layout should be loaded and if A is choosen later, that should come up. I can create different XAML layouts and use the OnNavigateTo Method, but i think its not very efficient. Is there a way, i can group the XAML Layouts together so that it can switch between them easily?.. I have heard of using templates, but can't really find any concrete example of how it works. Any help or links will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this in many different ways. If you are not supposed to load the layout *on the same page*, create 4 separate pages for each view and navigate to correct page.

If you are required to update the current view, you can choose one of the following:
 - Place all four layouts into each own Grid and set `Visibility="Collapsed"` for each one. Then, when you need to show a layout, simply change its Visibility to True.
 - Same as above, but use Visual States to add some animations.
 - Create 4 user controls and dynamically create the one you need and add it to the current page.

You need to account for several factors here:
 - Clean code and clean design.
 - Animations and transitions.
 - What about Back key? If user is supposed to navigate back to selection screen once he is done, consider navigating to separate pages.

Don't forget the last point, it may be crucial when choosing the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding you do not need to use templates. Since there are four different actions that have four different views associated with them, there shouldn't really be a problem with having a separate page for each action.

The problem might also be this - how different are the layouts? If data is the only thing that changes across them, you might think about having a view model to bind to and simply change the bindable source.

**Bottom line:** just use pages, or a single page bound to dynamic data, depending on your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

In my knowledge , I ask you to prefer the UserControls implementation in your UI. You can have A,B,C and D layouts as a separate UserControls and can have those UserControls in the same page. Just make the visibility changes based on the condition that recognize it in the code behind. I think it may help you.